# Spring actuator giving 404 Not found error even after setting server.servlet.contextPath

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-actuator

I have a spring batch project (Using Gradle). I want to the project to be integrated with Actuator.

I have added this to import to gradle
`implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"`

In application.yaml, I have added

```
server:
  port: 8083
  servlet:
    context-path: "/test"
```

Now, when I try to hit - `http://localhost:8083/test/health`  on my local, I get error -

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-09-21T18:36:42.779+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/test/health"
}
```

On running the same endpoint on browser, I see this error-

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Sep 21 18:45:07 UTC 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

But when I hit other endpoints like `http://localhost:8083/nikhil/api/boot-appliation` , it works!

Any suggestions where I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By default the context-path is `/`, and the actuator endpoint is:

```
/actuator/health
```

With the context-path set to `/test`, the actuator endpoint is:

```
/test/actuator/health
```

The `/actuator` portion of the url is from `management.endpoints.web.base-path` property. I think this is what you meant to set:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: /actuator
```

So, all together, if your configuration is this:

```
server:
  port: 8083
  servlet:
    context-path: /
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: "/test"
```

Your actuator endpoint will be:

```
/test/health
```